# Adobe PDF SDK - PDDocColorConvertEmbedOutputIntent and PDFA

Tags: sdk, pdf-generation, adobe, adobe-pdf-library

I am using the Datalogics library 9.1 and I am trying to embed an OutputIntent in a PDF I am creating so that it will be compliant with PDFA-1B.

I'm using PdDocColorConvertEmbedOutputIntent to do so and the function call is succeeding. The intent is getting in there, I can see it in Adobe Preflight. But certain PDFA verifiers still do not like what I'm creating.

I think it may be because the PDFA/s I create with this method have an outputIntent with a subtype of "GTS_PDFX" (as shown in Preflight).  I believe it needs to be "GTS_PDFA".  I see nowhere to specify the subtype of the output intent in the PdDocColorConvertEmbedOutputIntent parameters. This meethod seems to automatically choose the "GTS_PDFX" subtype and not allow me to choose anything else.

Basically, I'm just reading an ICC profile into pBuffer from a file, creating the profile and embedding it as below.

```
 AC_Profile profile = NULL;
 ACMakeBufferProfile(&profile,pBuffer,nSize);
 PDDocColorConvertEmbedOutputIntent(m_pDoc,profile);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 9.1 API and early versions of the 10 API have no parameter to supply to PdDocColorConvertEmbedOutputIntent () to specify the subtype. At the time of creation there was only one subtype "GTS_PDFX" and was hard coded into the API.

Manipulation at the COS layer will be necessary to affect a change to the subtype.